# Rails - How to use find or create with a default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have the following:

```
    conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_create_by_conversation_id(conversation.id)
```

This correctly creates a record, problem is the default value of conversation.read is false.

In this particular method I want the default value to be true when creating the record. Right now the only way I got this to work was by the following:

```
    conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_create_by_conversation_id(conversation.id)
    conversation_participation.read = true
    conversation_participation.save
```

Problem is this hits the DB twice. How can I use find_or_create and set the default :read => true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `find_or_initialize_by...`

Then set your `read` attribute as normal

```
conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_initialize_by_conversation_id(conversation.id)
conversation_participation.read = true
conversation_participation.save
```

Or

```
conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_initialize_by_conversation_id_and_read(conversation.id, true)
conversation_participation.save
```

With `after_initialize` (Oh.. you deleted your comment, but here is something for that just in case)

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::base
  def after_initialize
    self.read ||= true # true if not already set
  end
end
```

Then you can do `find_or_create|initialize_by...` or which ever way you wish to proceed.

More on [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) if you are interest.

Comment: if you want to set a default value in there, you can look into `after_initialize`

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> Use the `find_or_initialize_by_`
>   finder if you want to return a new
>   record without saving it first.

So something like this:

```
conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_initialize_by_conversation_id(conversation.id)
conversation_participation.read = true
conversation_participation.save
```

This should just do an `INSERT` instead of an `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conversation_participation = @user.conversation_participations.find_or_create_by_conversation_id_and_read(conversation.id, true)
```

Comment: Wait but that's no good, because if a conversation_participation exists with a read of false, which is very valid, this will create a new record, no?